# Python Ubuntu pypxlib stack smashing detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, paradox

I have a simple code to convert the Paradox DB to a dictionary and save it in a .dat with `pickle`.

In Windows, all works great but in Ubuntu 20 Server and venv for `python 3.8` I have this issue.

> *** stack smashing detected ***:
> terminated Aborted (core dumped)

This is the error in my code:

```
from pypxlib import Table
table = Table("/complete/path/database.DB")
for x in table:
    print(x)
```

Has someone any idea about this?

Comment: Possibly a bug in pypxlib. How did you install pypxlib on the Ubuntu box?

Comment: I install it in the same way of i make in Windows. pip install pypxlib i try in two diferent ubuntu server with the same result. Thanks

Comment: I would not be surprised if this is due to some specific Windows encoding stuff going on, since Paradox (BDE) is a Windows-only legacy database system.